# thickbox not displaying content in IE6

Tags: internet-explorer-6, thickbox

hello i am using thickbox as an information popup. it works well in IE7/8 & FF but in IE6 it does not display the content just garbled characters. i have attached my code and would be grateful if someone could tell me what the problem is? many thanks.

```
<a href="faq/whyreg.php?height=220&width=400" class="view thickbox" title="Registration has its benefits"> Answer</a>
```

and the doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

screengrabs

IE6
http://i53.tinypic.com/9gm4jb.png

IE8
http://i56.tinypic.com/55qexf.png

Comment: Could it be the document encoding?

Comment: I was wondering if the HTML file were saved in some sort of odd character encoding (or PHP is set to output in some sort of odd character encoding). Could you try it without the DTD?

Comment: just how important is IE6 support to you? My recommendation would be to drop support for it on your site -- it has less than 2% of the browser market share now, and is falling every month. It long ago reached the point where it wasn't worth the effort to keep supporting it. (I'd also add that the Thickbox site itself has a note dated over a year and a half ago that it isn't being supported any more and recommending users to switch to an alternative, including links to several options)

Comment: @justin still the same. thanks @spudley. it is not important to me but it is to the client. i am having no probs in IE7/8 or FF, so if poss i would like to use a solution. i have tried alternatives like shadowbox, dialog, facybox but prefer thickbox. thanks

Comment: If the client insists on IE6, then double your prices.  ;-)

Comment: wish it was just about price spudley :-) need to keep a happy client. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation in the following link:

[JQuery Thick box][1]

**[1]: http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/**

And use the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="thickbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function show_search (value)
  { 
   var url= 'http://www.google.com'; 
   tb_show('Change Details','"+url+"');   
   setTimeout("remove()",1*100);
   return false;
  }
  function remove()
  { 
    tb_remove();    
    alert("check");
   } 
 </script> 
</head> 
<body>
<form id="hotel_search_popup">
<h2>Search Hotels</h2>
<input name="category"  type="radio" value="F"  class="radioSearch"  onclick="return show_search(this.value);"/>
<label>Flight</label>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```